# How to get cached responses using Alamofire while app is in offline?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

After I got a `response` via Alamofire, **in some cases**, implementing a **database** or managing local storage **myself** (file etc.) can be a bit **overkill**.

I know about Alamofire's `requestCachePolicy` and it is already caching responses *(based on `cache-control`'s `max-age`)*, but this has more to do with reducing the number of requests/improve the experience **when online**.

**But is it possible to use the cached response when I have no connection available via Alamofire?** *(Does Alamofire provide some kind of convenient way to handle this)*

Comment: Why don't use AwesomeCache pod, look this is the repo, https://github.com/aschuch/AwesomeCache i was working in one application with your requirement and I achieve with this pod, I hope this helps you

Comment: There are many libraries like this, but I'm not looking for 3rd party cache libraries. This kind of falls within the *managing local storage myself* part of my Q.

Comment: @JakubTruhlář . Hi, i am working alamofire swift 3 , i want cache the json object. Please guide me how to achieve this . Thank  you

Comment: From my understanding, this is the default behavior of Alamofire, since it is the default behavior of the underlying URLSession API. This documentation describes the default behavior: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy

If you're still having issues, your server might not be returning the appropriate cache headers in the response, such as "Cache-Control".

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this behaviour. You should try to modify the "on going" request is about to be perfomed and setting the flag `returnCacheDataDontLoad` or `returnCacheDataElseLoad` for getting the desired behaviour. (Depends of your needs)

Something like:

```
var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://foo.bar.com/res")!)
if noInternet {
    req.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataDontLoad
}
```

Also make sure about the caching policies the app is negotiating with the server just in case you need to tweak it as well.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: My Api contains headers is this possible in the same way?